# Comparing two values in Rcpp without casting to specific type

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I seek to compare two generic R values in C++ using Rcpp. How can I compare two values without casting them to specific types in C++?

The code that explains my issue is as follows,

```
require("Rcpp")
require("inline")
src <- "return wrap(x1 == x2);"

fun <- cxxfunction(signature(x1 = "SEXP", x2 = "SEXP"), src, plugin = "Rcpp")

fun("a", "a")

to_cmp <- "a"

fun(to_cmp, to_cmp)
```

It now gives `FALSE` and `TRUE` where I want it to yield `TRUE` and `TRUE`.

Since my goal is to implement a data structure in C++ I would prefer to potential user defined `==` methods.

## Possible approach

One approach that I tried is,

require("Rcpp")

```
src <- '
Language call("\`==\`", x1, x2);

return call.eval();
'

fun <- cxxfunction(signature(x1 = "SEXP", x2 = "SEXP"), src, plugin = "Rcpp")

fun("a", "a")

to_cmp <- "a"

fun(to_cmp, to_cmp)
```

However, when I run this I get `` Error: could not find function "`==`" ``

Comment: without giving it a type, it doesn't know which `operator==` it's supposed to use

Comment: I know that that is an issue but I was just wondering whether there is a way I can call the R `==` operator or whether any syntactic sugar exists for this.

Comment: function overloading could be an idea

Comment: This question is related to a general data structure that should be able to hold any kind of information so I guess that overloading would require all possible combinations. Or do you have another view on this?

Comment: R provides the `R_compute_identical(SEXP, SEXP, int)` API as well: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/96f1cea9a25143699ac4536696d5a0a130a9dbbe/src/include/Rinternals.h#L1120-L1130

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are on the right track with using the generic `SEXP` input object tag. To get this to work one needs to use C++ templates in addition to `TYPEOF()`. The prior enables the correct vector creation in the comparison function to be hooked in with *Rcpp* sugar while the latter enables the correct check and dispatch to occur.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

template <int RTYPE>
Rcpp::LogicalVector compare_me(Rcpp::Vector<RTYPE> x, Rcpp::Vector<RTYPE> y) {
    return x == y;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::LogicalVector compare_objects(SEXP x, SEXP y) {

    if (TYPEOF(x) == TYPEOF(y)) {
        switch (TYPEOF(x)) {
            case INTSXP:
                return compare_me<INTSXP>(x, y);
            case REALSXP:
                return compare_me<REALSXP>(x, y);
            case STRSXP:
                return compare_me<STRSXP>(x, y);
            default:
                Rcpp::stop("Type not supported");
        }
    } else {
        Rcpp::stop("Objects are of different type");
    }

    // Never used, but necessary to avoid the compiler complaining
    // about a missing return statement
    return Rcpp::LogicalVector(); 
}
```

Example:

```
to_cmp <- "a"
compare_objects(to_cmp, to_cmp)
```

Output:

```
[1] TRUE
```

Also, the above is for use with `Rcpp::sourceCpp()`. I would encourage you to switch from using `inline` to using `Rcpp::cppFunction()` for function definitions as it allows you to focus on the computation and *not* the setup.

Comment: Thanks, I was working with that and `boost::variant` to hide most of the complexity. The problem is that this still does not support user defined `==`. Thanks for pointing out `Rcpp::sourceCpp()`, I just wanted to simplify the problem for SO.